# ngAfterContentChecked causing data to not display

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am having to use ngAfterContentChecked as shown below:

```
 ngAfterContentChecked() {
   this.cdr.detectChanges();
 }
```

This is needed as a workaround for the error: 'expression has changed after it was checked', but now I have a blank screen where the data should be.. I can even change the td data to plain text but still nothing.

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[increment()]">
         <td>{{item}}</td>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Here is the method the ngFor is using:

```
increment() {
   if (this.counter < this.messages.length) {
      return this.counter++;
   }
```

[Angular 2+ Expression has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683111/angular-2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked?noredirect=1#comment86378861_49683111)

[image: messageSplit array]

[image]

Comment: does it work when you remove the ngAfterContentChecked  function?

Comment: Yes the table will be populated for a few seconds if I remove it, but then I have the 'expression has changed after it was checked' error

Comment: can you attach the sample json of the messages. It would be easy for me to find a solution for this

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I've added a link to a previous issue I had regarding the I previously mentioned error.It has the relevant project code including a screen shot of the messageSplit array in the console. Does this help? thanks

Comment: ok give me few minutes I'll check it out @Ryn9011

Comment: @Ryn9011 did you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @SuvethanNantha no errors in the console when using ngAfterContentChecked()

Comment: @Ryn9011 If you can share the messages sample json and messageSplit sample json. It will be easy for me to fix this issue

Comment: @SuvethanNantha, Sorry there is no json to share. messages are passed in as a string and then are spliced into messageSplit. I have attached a screen shot of messageSplit array

Comment: The intention is for each sub array (in this case array 1 - 30) to be displayed in a td. Sorry for the poor test data in the screenshot. testing was becoming tedious so I was inputting rubbish

Comment: @Ryn9011 so your intention is to just display array 1 -30 in td is that so? I noticed some of the values are not formatted in the sub array. for example, if you take the first sub array first element it has something like this ['Job #334343' Do I need to worry about this or I can just display whatever in the sub arrays?

Comment: @Ryn9011 you said you spliced into messageSplit, then what is this.messages.length in the code? can you explain it?

Comment: @SuvethanNantha I've added another screenshot of the desired outcome. this is with ngAfterContentChecked() removed and so after a few seconds I get the error mentioned above and the data disappears. messages.length is just my amature way of limiting the count variable, but it isn't affecting the issue and can be removed